# certificate was checked as valid but all browsers iOS and mac osx are invalid

Tags: macos, security, ssl

Certificate error on iOS safari, chrome and macOS chrome and safari.

iOS 13 & MacOS 10.15 have started imposing stricter requirements for trusted certificates https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210176

I've ran checks on multiple SSL checkers which showed that the certificate is valid, but i still can't load the site.
I've verified the following requirements:

- TLS server certificates and issuing CAs using RSA keys must use key sizes greater than or equal to 2048 bits. Certificates using RSA key sizes smaller than 2048 bits are no longer trusted for TLS.
- TLS server certificates and issuing CAs must use a hash algorithm from the SHA-2 family in the signature algorithm. SHA-1 signed certificates are no longer trusted for TLS.
- TLS server certificates must present the DNS name of the server in the Subject Alternative Name extension of the certificate. DNS names in the CommonName of a certificate are no longer trusted.

[image]
[image][image]

Anybody know what's wrong with the certificate? SSL checkers have already verified the certificate chain is complete and

Comment: This might not be it, but usually the "Basic Constraints" extension is "Critical: YES" (and of course, "Certificate Authority: NO").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your sites https://uat.iconnect.care/ and https://www.iconnect.care/.

Firefox does not have any problems on your two sites.

Chrome has no problem with https://uat.iconnect.care/,
but on the site https://www.iconnect.care/ reports:

[image]

The error NET::ERR_CERTIFICATE_TRANSPARENCY_REQUIRED seems to be related
to the fact that
Chrome now requires for some certificate authorities that the
SSL security certificates be registered into Certificate Transparency
(https://www.certificate-transparency.org).

I therefore looked into the certificates on your two websites and they
are not the same. I get the following certificate thumbprints:

- https://uat.iconnect.care/ : 29beacb232616ff1a23d00dd28a4ba2e7c9310ab
- https://www.iconnect.care/ : 4fc140fddcb53df077e681c9f12e0bd0c9577e27

This proves that these are two different certificates.

For checking Certificate Transparency, I verified that
the website https://uat.iconnect.care/ has this information
in the field *SCT List*:

[image]

However, the certificate used for https://www.iconnect.care/
does not have it:

[image]

**Conclusion:** The certificate used for https://www.iconnect.care/
is not registered into Certificate Transparency and cannot be used
on browsers that check it, especially Chrome.
Ask GlobalSign to reissue the certificate, and this time to register it
with Certificate Transparency.
Or replace the certificate for the site with the other one.

Comment: My uat.iconnect.care site is working fine using a cert with dates encipherment though

Comment: I missed the fact that this certificate has two extensions, the first apparently for code signing and the second for SSL. Strange. I never met before a dual-purpose certificate, but I haven't bought any for some years now, so it might be a new development. Questions: (1) Perhaps you could give us the link to your site so we can verify the certificate (2) Does this also happen with Firefox? (3) Does it happen from a Windows computer?

Comment: https://uat.iconnect.care & https://www.iconnect.care

Comment: The latter hasnt been deployed, but curl will return a blank html page

Comment: Haven’t tried on windows machine, but weird for OV cert to work but not EV

Comment: I think I found it, but had to rewrite my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Apple enforces more requirements than just those. In particular, it has a [Certificate Transparency policy](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205280) requiring that certificates be logged in a public CT log, **and** that the proof of inclusion in CT logs be provided during the same TLS handshake (without requiring the browser to go looking on its own).

The proofs (SCTs) can be either embedded within the certificate itself as an extension, or provided using OCSP Stapling if the webserver is configured for that.

However, your site has neither of those. Although the corresponding "pre-certificate" *has* indeed been submitted to various CT logs, the "final" certificate installed on your webserver is missing the 'CT Signed Certificate Timestamps' (1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.4.2) extension, and the webserver does not offer OCSP Stapling during the TLS handshake, either.

Google Chrome on other platforms has a similar policy, although so far only for EV certificates. When connecting from Windows it shows ERR_CERTIFICATE_TRANSPARENCY_REQUIRED.

---

Blanking out the site's name really makes such questions difficult and/or annoying to answer, because the answer depends not only on the certificate itself but also on the webserver's configuration – information about OCSP stapling was obtained by directly testing your webserver's TLS response, and of course nobody knows whether the provided screenshots include *all* certificate details, or whether some of them have been cropped off.

Fortunately, the unedited certificate can be found in the same CT logs mentioned above, based on its Serial Number and/or Subject Key Identifier (or even based on the issue/expiry dates if necessary), so your site's name is publicly known anyway.

Comment: It’s https://www.iconnect.care I can curl and get a basic html but non of the devices work

Comment: i am using nginx and my other servers using OV certificates didn't have this problem, this is actually an EV certificate, what further configuration would help?

Comment: Enable OCSP Stapling on the web server -- or ask the certificate issuer about "embedded SCTs".